# Deploy Qt application that uses MySQL

Tags: mysql, qt

I am thinking about developing an application to store a movie database, allowing the user to store information about which movies it owns, which movies it wants to see, etc.
I was thinking of developing this application with the Qt framework and using MySQL to to the database part.

However, I have a few questions. When deploying my application on other machines, won't I need MySQL installed there too? Or will the .dll suffice? 
Can I connect to a database that does not exist, on a machine that does not have MySQL installed?

Comment: You can't connect to a database on a machine that doesn't have the database installed.

Comment: So what I want to do is impossible? I would have to store all that information in regular files?

Comment: Well, if there's no MySQL or any other daemon that allows you to store data within it - *how* would you do it then? :) So yes, you'd have to resort to either shipping MySQL with your app and installing it or create your own storage using files.

Comment: I have done a bit of research, and apparently, I can use SQLite for that. Seems I can embed it in my application. I have to try a few things first before assuming it works.

Comment: Well, seems like SQLite is exactly what I am looking for. It creates a file, locally, and I am able to use the default QT SQL classes to access it. I think this is how I can solve my problem.